# Understanding a Perl one-liner

Tags: perl, command-line, process, aix

I was looking at a way to check the memory usage of processes on AIX and found [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.performance/mem_use_processes.htm), listing this command:

```
# svmon -Pt15 | perl -e 'while(<>){print if($.==2||$&&&!$s++);$.=0 if(/^-+$/)}'
```

It works fine for my purpose, but I would like to understand how the Perl one-liner part works.

I know it's parsing the output of the `svmon` command. I already understood the part `$.==2` which output the 2nd line. The part `$.=0` resets the line number so it can do the same processing for each process listed by `svmon`.

However I'm at loss to understand the part `||$&&&!$s++`. There is a OR. `$&` is the matched part (of what?) and && is the AND operator, but I'm not sure I'm decomposing it correctly either.

`svmon` returns (without any redirection) a similar block of lines per process. The first lines are similar to:

```
# svmon -Pt15 | head -n 20

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Pid Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual 64-bit Mthrd  16MB
12058652 java            579432     8261   397386   824106      Y     Y     N

     PageSize                Inuse        Pin       Pgsp    Virtual
     s    4 KB               67560        309       1610      40138
     m   64 KB               31992        497      24736      48998

    Vsid      Esid Type Description              PSize  Inuse   Pin Pgsp Virtual
  c86b4c        7e work text data BSS heap           m   4096     0   43    4096
  c30d43        7f work text data BSS heap           m   4096     0  215    4096
  db2358        68 work text data BSS heap           m   4089     0 3667    4096
  d25056        69 work text data BSS heap           m   4057     0  585    4096
  99d59b      1002 work text data BSS heap           m   3461     0 2061    4082
  b531b1        7d work text data BSS heap           m   3440     0   39    3440
  a551a7      1001 work text data BSS heap           m   2933     0 2597    3767
  970017  90000000 work shared library text          m   2172     0  213    2413
  ca3c48        6a work text data BSS heap           m   2090     0 2006    4096
  ade32e         4 work text or shared-lib code seg sm  25389     0    0   25389
... (tons of lines)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Pid Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual 64-bit Mthrd  16MB
 6094910 java            494585     8110     5754   484444      Y     Y     N

     PageSize                Inuse        Pin       Pgsp    Virtual
     s    4 KB               31257        158       1610      16780
     m   64 KB               28958        497        259      29229

    Vsid      Esid Type Description              PSize  Inuse   Pin Pgsp Virtual
  a31ba7         8 work text or shared-lib code seg  m   4096     0    0    4096
  da3159         6 work text or shared-lib code seg  m   4096     0    0    4096
... repeated several times
```

The processed output with the perl part returns the headers, the dash line and one line per process, with the command and memory details:

```
# svmon -Pt15 | perl -e 'while(<>){print if($.==2||$&&&!$s++);$.=0 if(/^-+$/)}'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Pid Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual 64-bit Mthrd  16MB
12058652 java            579438     8261   397386   824106      Y     Y     N
 6094910 java            494583     8110     5754   484444      Y     Y     N
 5046378 java            382458     8217     5738   339847      Y     Y     N
21102818 java            352534     8149     5738   305644      Y     Y     N
18219048 java            321394     8081   176586   340617      Y     Y     N
18612404 java            235323     8161   100746   267565      Y     Y     N
 3735554 java            195412     8118   125306   222885      Y     Y     N
24772644 java            185403     8209    88474   202652      Y     Y     N
25559102 java            143341     8095     5738   118094      Y     Y     N
11272240 java            137082     8193    82810   167151      Y     Y     N
18874550 java            131531     8129    79898   144249      Y     Y     N
 5505082 java            121320     8075    50922   136195      Y     Y     N
```

Comment: It is a needlessly complicated one-liner, and it looks like it might be fragile. (Ab)using `$.` looks very sketchy.

Comment: Can the same result be done in a simpler, more robust way?

Comment: Almost certainly, although it would be somewhat of a guesswork without a definition, or sample of the input.

Comment: Command output has been added, with and without the perl part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -e 'while(<>){print if($.==2||$&&&!$s++);$.=0 if(/^-+$/)}'
```

This looks -- at first glance -- like something meant to print every other line, and also the first line after a `---` line. Lets take a look at the parts.

`while(<>) { ... }` reads standard input (or a file, if you provide arguments) in a line-by-line mode. The most common way to do this in a one-liner is to use the `-n` or `-p` switch. I.e. this:

```
perl -e 'while(<>) { ... }'
```

Is the same as this:

```
perl -ne ' ... '
```

`print if` will print `$_`, one of the read lines, if the condition following it is true. The condition `if ( $. == 2 || $& && !$s++ )` is a clunky piece of horse manure. Lets dissect it.

First of all, lets note that it consists of two statements, joined with `||`, meaning the whole statement is true, if either of the statements are true. Second of all, note that it is short-circuiting, meaning that the right hand statement is never evaluated if the left one is true. This is relevant here because of the counter variable `$s`.

[`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.) is the built-in variable for line number on the last input file handle accessed. It can be manipulated, but god knows why one would want to. In this case, if the line number is `2`, the line is printed.

If `$.` is not `2`, the right hand statement is checked. It is also a chained statement, with `&&`, meaning both must be true. In reality, all three statements are chained with each other: `a || b && c`, making this a rather complicated mess of [operator precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity). Luckily (?), it seems to mean what we assume it means: `(a || (b && c))`. So, if `$&` is true, and `!$s++` is true, the print goes through. The [increment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) on the right side of the variable returns the value *before* being incremented, in this case it returns `0` the first time the code is run, which negated turns into `1`, a true value. All times after that, `!$s++` returns false. This is a common Perl idiom to return true only for the first encountered value.

Phew!

The part after that resets `$.` to `0` if there is a line that consists only of dashes `----`. Presumably this is done to separate "records", e.g.:

```
foo
bar
------
next
...
```

But that begs the question why `!$s++`? Do we always print the second line of every record? We always print the first line that is "not line #2", that is preceded by a line of "just" dashes `----`.

So lets try and summarize... this will print

- Line number 2 in the input, *or* the 2nd line after a line of only dashes `----`, *if* there are no lines of only dashes in between.
- The first line after the first line of only dashes it finds (and only the first)

> Can the same result be done in a simpler, more robust way?

Oh yes, certainly. Here's an example of doing the same thing, but with simpler tools:

```
$ perl -ne'if ($. <= 3) { print } elsif (/^-+$/) { <>; print <>.""; }'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Pid Command          Inuse      Pin     Pgsp  Virtual 64-bit Mthrd  16MB
12058652 java            579432     8261   397386   824106      Y     Y     N
 6094910 java            494585     8110     5754   484444      Y     Y     N
99058652 java            579432     8261   397386   824106      Y     Y     N
22058652 java            579432     8261   397386   824106      Y     Y     N
```

This basically reads like english, which is always nice. It takes the first three lines, and prints them, then checks for the "dash line", discards the line after it, and prints the next. I use the concatenation operator `.` to put the file handle in scalar context, to just print one line. An alternative is to use a scalar variable and print that.

Is this the best way? Well... it is a simple way. You could improve it lots by creating a program file, which would be run like:

```
svmon -Pt15 | perl program.pl
```

Combine it with the linux systems handy features, and you have a new command at your disposal.

That program could be something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print <> . "" for 1 .. 3;

while (<>) {
    if (/^-+$/) {
        <>;
        print <> . "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are decomposing it correctly, as we can verify with [B::Deparse](http://p3rl.org/B::Deparse):

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'while(<>){print if($.==2||$&&&!$s++);$.=0 if(/^-+$/)}'
while (defined(($_ = <ARGV>))) {
    ((($. == 2) || ($& && (!($s++)))) and print($_));
    (/^-+$/ and ($. = 0));
}
```

The `$&` contains the last match, in this case there's only one place where matching happens: `/^-+$/`.

`!$s++` is true only when `$s++` is false, i.e. on the very first match (`$& && !$s++`).

Comment: Thanks! But what about the `$s++` path? It's incrementing something but I couldn't find the purpose.

Comment: Can you add the output of `svmon` to the question?

Comment: The output after perl parses it, or the raw output? If the later, it's huge (4813 lines on my server). I cannot host it anywhere either, for confidentiality reasons, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Snark: Check the update. Also read [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `!$s++` is a Perl idiom for finding duplicates. For example, `@unique = grep !$seen{$_}++, @list;`. In this case, it will prevent `print` from being reached more than once.